# Show more snap install info in command line?

Tags: command-line, package-management, snap, snap-store

When I install Snap packages via Terminal, it doesn't show my that much info. I want to see more information, such as dependencies installed, etc.

Also, I don't like it that after it displays something, it clears it and displays the next thing. Here's what I mean:

First, it says something like this:

```
Download snap "snap" (5555) from channel "latest/stable" ...
```

Then, it completely clears that text and says something different like:

```
Mount snap "snap" ...
```

I would at least like it to stop clearing these messages and just display them like a normal package manager. For example, apt doesn't clear, it keeps displaying everything. Imagine there's something I'd like to see and I step away from the screen for a sec and I'm not able to see it...

#### Apt vs Snap

If you're confused, here's the difference between what I would see when I go back to the screen in apt vs snap.

Apt:

```
Preparing to unpack .../language-pack-gnome-en_1%3a20.04+20220211_all.deb ...
Unpacking language-pack-gnome-en (1:20.04+20220211) over (1:20.04+20210802) ...
Preparing to unpack .../language-pack-gnome-en-base_1%3a20.04+20220211_all.deb ...
Unpacking language-pack-gnome-en-base (1:20.04+20220211) over (1:20.04+20210802) ...
Setting up language-pack-gnome-en (1:20.04+20220211) ...
Setting up language-pack-gnome-en-base (1:20.04+20220211) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
~$
```

Snap:

```
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
~$
```

Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This seems like a Rant In Disguise more than a question. Snaps don't have any dependencies, nor compressed archives to unpack into the filesystem, nor system integration to set up beyond what is shown in your example, so it's unclear what you are looking for.

Comment: I want it to stop clearing the messages and I want them to show up as they come, not cleared.

Comment: Then you must either use one of the `debug` commands (see `man snap`) or ask the snap developers for the feature. You will likely need to justify a use case for them to expend the effort -- "I want it" is unlikely to sell them on the prospect. And, of course, it's open source -- you are welcome to develop the feature yourself and contribute it to snapd.

Comment: Intuitively, people who HIDE information are not to be trusted. The community already distrusts  snaps. This hostile reaction to a request for greater transparency is further evidence to support the hypothesis that this distrust is warranted.

Comment: People who react to legitimate requests for information using an account which hides their identity do so for a reason. This is NOT building trust with the community.